# Firebase reporting on orders collection / sum values from nodes

Tags: firebase

I am investigating chances to use Firebase for my next project.I spent several days reading and building a "prove of concepts" project. In the demo project i build a shopping cart.In the admin section i can create products, and the client can buy it.When the client checks out i push to the closed-orders node a complex object which stores all data for the deal like this simplified version:

```
 closed-orders
      -order_id
          -date
          -client_id
          -products
              -product_id
                 -sale_price
                 -delivery_price
                 -qùantity
              -product_id
                  -sale_price
                  -delivery_price  
                  -quantity  
              ....more products sold in this order
next order....
```

It is easy to do it that way and i can acces every different order and show it in the admin, but i want to make queries about the total sales, sales by product and a query about the profit.
Example question asked
1.What is the total quantites sold for every product from date1 to date2
2.What is the total turnover from date1 to date2
3.What is the profit for date1 to date2.

I want to answer this questions without downloading the whole dataset in the brwoser of course, because i do not think i can afford to pay for such bandwidth.Orders for one year could be tens of thousands:)
I wrote about Elastic search, keen.io but i am not sure exactly what functionality they offer and if it will answer my questions in a bandwidth friendly way.